# Random access to SD card using SD.h or another library (ESP32)

Tags: esp32, sd, sd.h

I'm trying to use a SD card with my ESP32 in order to save some variables in a txt file. Each variable uses 1 byte, so they can be represented by an 8 bit extended ASCII character.

The issue is it seems that the SD.h library has only 3 open modes (Read only, `FILE_WRITE`, `FILE_APPEND`), and I cannot figure out how to use random access for writing a specific byte of the file.

Imagine the situation: I have a file called `myFile.txt` which initially has a size of 5 bytes, and its content is:
`abcde`

The code I'm using is the following:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define SD_CS_PIN 5

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS_PIN)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");



  myFile = SD.open("/myFile.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  myFile.seek(3);
  myFile.write('a');
  myFile.close();

}

void loop() {}
```

But after running the code, the file has an unexpected behaviour, its size changes from 5 bytes to 4 bytes, and its content is:
`abca`
instead of the expected
`abcae`

I know it happens because when writing into the file I'm using the open mode `FILE_WRITE` which uses the `FILE_APPEND` mode internally, so when doing `myFile.seek(3);`, I'm truncating the file to 4 bytes since the `FILE_APPEND` mode needs to point to the end of the file.

So, my question is, how can I open a file in random access mode with SD.h, or another library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try to seek() to the end before close(). note: the SD library in ESP32 boards support package is different than the standard Arduino SD library.

Comment: @Juraj I tried it out but I got the same result, the first `myFile.seek(3);` truncates the file before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved!**

The solution was to migrate from the `SD` library to [`mySD`](https://github.com/nhatuan84/esp32-micro-sdcard), which seems to be a `SdFat` wrapper for ESP32.

You can see in the file [`mySD.h`](https://github.com/nhatuan84/esp32-micro-sdcard/blob/master/mySD.h#L30) that the `FILE_WRITE` mode is defined as:

```cpp
#define FILE_WRITE (F_READ | F_WRITE | F_CREAT)
```

Which means that it allows random access to the file for writing (`F_WRITE` instead of `FILE_APPEND`).

**PS:** I want to remark @Juraj comment since the forum is mainly for Arduino board questions

> the SD library in ESP32 boards support package is different than the standard Arduino SD library